# Ajax -access protected resource

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am just trying to access a webservice or any webpage for that matter through ajax(only ajax is allowed for some reasons).The webservice is protected by coroporate SSO. In the sense, when the webpage **X** is requested for the first time, you get redirected to the login page **Y**,which is outside of the app. Upon authentication,you get auto redirected to the page X. Subsequent requests to page **X** will work without authentication. Of course, all these are handled through cookies. Whether or not to display login page **Y** is determined by the presence/validity/content of a few cookies.

Now, I am trying to access this protected resource **X** through ajax. Is it possible to achieve this using ajax? How can cookies be handled in an ajax request?

Comment: if X is in your website and you are already logged in , it will not go to login page Y , as session is already there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX uses GET and POST requests, so cookies are sent in the same way as when you do a GET or POST request when loading a new page.